# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop - Tbody

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am facing the above error when running jest tests on a component.
npm start does not complain.

The component is as follows:

```
....
....

  const [Data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await getData();
      setData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

 displaydate = "11/07/2021"

  return (
    <Screen}>
      <NavElement />
      <Wrapper>
        <Container data-testid="testid">
          {displayDate != null && (
            <date>...</date>
          )}
          {Data.length != 0 ? (
            <>
              <table className="...">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody>
                  {Data.map(({ content, text, id, index }) => (
                    <>
                      <tr key={index} data-testid="tid">
                        <td>{text}</td>
                        {content != null ? (
                          <td>
                            {" "}
                            <RichTextViewer input={content} />
                          </td>
                        ) : (
                          <td></td>
                        )}
                      </tr>
                    </>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </>
          ) : (
            <span></span>
          )}
        </Container>
      </Wrapper>
    </Screen>
  );
```

I did check the index, it is good.
tr is the outermost parent element, I have added a key to this.

The error when I run the test says:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

The error points to:

```
 <table className="...">
      84 |                 <thead></thead>
    > 85 |                 <tbody>
         |                 ^
           ...
           ...
```

Not sure how to go about this.
I have gone through the various other questions on the forum.
All the answers say , the outermost/nearest parent element needs to have a unique key.
which is there.

Also, I am testing this with just one element, so don't think its a case of duplicate keys.

Comment: remove the fragment `<>` around your `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React docs:

> "You can use `<></>` the same way you’d use any other element except that it doesn’t support keys or attributes."

So as @thedude said, remove the fragment shorthand syntax.

The confusion is because you're not seeing the fragment when inspecting the DOM because fragments don't render to the DOM.

For future reference, if you did need to use fragments this way, you can use the longhand syntax:

```
<React.Fragment key={index}>...</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fragment around the tr.
Answer is in the comment above by @thedude.